# Bing Maps Angular MapComponent: TypeError: nativeElement undefined

Tags: angular, components, bing-maps

I am getting the following error on load of my custom component, MapComponent.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined at MapComponent.ngOnInit
```

I am getting an error regarding the MapComponent I am using for a Bing Maps location plotter.

Here is the component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  reports: Report[] = [];

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
    console.log("start");
    this.getAllReports();
    console.log("finished reports");
    //adds markers to map
    this._markers.push({ latitude: 29.714994, longitude: -95.46244})
    console.log("pushed a marker");
    for(let i:number=0; i<20; i++){
      this._markers.push({ latitude: 29.714994 + Math.random() - Math.random(), longitude: -95.46244 + Math.random() - Math.random()});
    }
  }

  _markerTypeId = MarkerTypeId;
  _options: IMapOptions = {
    disableBirdseye: false,
    disableStreetside: false,
    navigationBarMode: 1,
    zoom: 6
  };

  _box: IBox = {
    maxLatitude: 32,
    maxLongitude: -92,
    minLatitude: 29,
    minLongitude: -98
  };

  _iconInfo: IMarkerIconInfo = {
    markerType: MarkerTypeId.CanvasMarker,
    rotation: 45,
    drawingOffset: { x: 12, y: 0 },
    points: [
      { x: 5, y: 20 },
      { x: 12, y: 15 },
      { x: 19, y: 20 },
      { x: 12, y: 0 }
    ],
    color: '#f00',
    size: { width: 24, height: 24 }
  };

  _markers: Array<ILatLong> = new Array<ILatLong>();

  _click(index: number){
    console.log(`Marker ${index} says: hello world...`);
  }

}
```

Here is the associated component.html

```
<div style="height: 600px">
  <x-map #xmap [Options]="_options" [Box]="_box">
    <x-map-marker *ngFor="let m of _markers; let i=index" [Latitude]="m.latitude" [Longitude]="m.longitude" [Title]="'My Marker ' + i.toString()" [IconInfo]="_iconInfo">
    </x-map-marker>
  </x-map>
</div>
```

I am new to Angular, and I do not know how to pinpoint what to do to fix this error, especially if the error is happening within the MapComponent (a maintained component I npm'ed). None of my console.log statements run either (see the constructor), meaning to say that the error might be happening before the component is initialized?

EDIT WHILE WRITING THIS: It seems that I named my custom component MapComponent. There is also a MapComponent in the MapModule / angular-maps.js I am using. Is this the source of my problem? The error is happening in the MapComponent from the MapModule, not the MapComponent I created (Google Chrome debugging points to the file where the error originates).

[image]

Any suggestions will help. Tell me where to look!

Comment: I don't see you implementing an ngOnInit method in your component. Just add this method: ngOnInit () {} and see what happens

Comment: Yea, I can add it. But, the ngOnInit that is breaking is from the MapComponent from an angular module I downloaded. I know its bad that I have a custom component that is using a component from angular of the same name. Found out too late.

Comment: Then I think you should follow the steps as described in the ReadMe of the repo and check whether your Angular version is supported

Comment: Just for an update: I ended up refactoring my custom component. Same error. I'll check angular version and map are compatible

Comment: See this https://github.com/infusion-code/angular-maps/issues/127

Comment: yikes. thanks for the help. This answers it. Never been in this situation before. How do I resolve this question? Wanna give some props to u for helping as well.